# Unable to bake normalmap without artifacts

Tags: baking, normal-map

I've got 2 human male meshes from an asset-webside. Those are low-Poly and high-poly versions of a human.

I tried to bake the normals for the low poly version multiple times with different approaches but got some weird resulst every time (Image as reference).

[image]

So far i tried:

- Different normal Map Sizes
- Many different ray distances
- Using a cage (minor improvement)
- Unwrapping the UV's in different shapes
- Using different materials
- Changing the sizes of the meshes or normals (ALT+S)
- Subdividing the low-poly version for more polies
- Shrinkwrap the to models to fit each other

At this point i don't have anymore ideas what setting i could change to make this work and couldn't find anymore tips on similar topics.

Maybe i'm just missing some small detail or doing some rookie mistake.

I'll include two blend files. One is the file at the very beginning and the second one is my result at the end.

- https://easyupload.io/m/h0jl79

If anybody got anymore ideas i would really appreciate your help!

UPDATE : Images

[image]

This is the base white material i'm using the whole time.

[image]

The same Error with a different material.

Comment: Hello, your links say that the file has been deleted, maybe use https://pasteall.org/blend/ But are you sure your original object normals are correctly oriented?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advise for the download. I tried that with no improvements unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scale is very small (0.01), first apply for both the 2 objects, then give a bit of *Extrusion* (I've tried 0.03), no need for *Maximum Ray Distance*. Also, use an *32-Bit Float* image:

[image]

Comment: First of thanks for the tip! It worked for me the first time i tried it. Unfortunately i didn't save the result image. I've been trying to recreate that image with the same steps but without any sucess. The normal map itself looks quite good to be hones but in the Viewport it's only working parcialy. Some areas look great but others are just painted even brighter then before?

Comment: could you please share your current file?

Comment: Of course : https://easyupload.io/gaxl34.

Comment: choose an Extrusion value of about 0.025 which seems like the best you can get, then you'll probably need to give it some correction in Paint mode, either in the 3D view or in the Image Editor

Comment: (which means use the eyedropper to get the blue color and paint over the bad colors)

Comment: Or another solution is to find the Extrusion value that will work for the bad parts, then mix 2 normal maps

Comment: Thank you for your solutions! I tried painting over the areas but it didn't fix the problem with the white spots. Like half of the meshes is this white tone and even after painting over those parts it stays the same. But the "deformation" of the meshe by the normal map changes as desired.

Comment: mmh I didn't see any white spot so I'm not sure what's happening in your case

Comment: I posted two picutres in the originals post from my viewport to clarify the issue.

Comment: ooh ok, I thought you were talking about the normal map colors. So you need to enable the 32-Bit Float option when you create your image, then select it in the Image Texture and bake again

Comment: The 32-Bit fixed it! Thank you so much :)